# Can anyone make me understand second and third paragraph?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Can anyone make me understand second and third paragraph ?

It is from book Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors

this is the previous page

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you don't understand?  In the second paragraph, for example, the order of a zero is just the multiplicity of a root of a polynomial.  Do you understand that?

Comment: i dont understand what does order of a zero means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every polynomial $p(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ splits into linear factors. $$p(z) = c(z-a_1)(z-a_2)\cdots(z-a_n)$$ for some complex numbers $c, a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$.  The $a_k$ are called the *zeros* (or the roots) of the polynomial.  Of course, some of the $a_k$ may be equal.  The number of times that a particular zero occurs in the list is called the *order* of the zero (or the multiplicity of the root).

For example, if $$p(z)=z^3(z-1)^2(z-2),$$ then

$0$ is a zero of order $3.$

$1$ is a zero of order $2.$

$2$ is a zero of order $1.$

Comment: Not every polynomial has leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thanks.  I'll correct it.